# Given a posdef matrix $M$, find $x$ such that $x_i = \operatorname{sign}\left(\sum_j M_{ij}x_j\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-analysis

Let $M$ be a real symmetric positive definite matrix. Can we characterize the sign vectors $x$, that satisfy the condition:
$$x_i = \operatorname{sign}\left(\sum_j M_{ij}x_j\right)$$
That is, this says that applying $M$ to the sign vector $x$, returns a vector in the same orthant as $x$, since
$$x_i\sum_j M_{ij}x_j \ge 0$$
How many such sign vectors can there be? I have the intuition it's no more than $2n$ (the dimension of the space), but I have no idea how to prove this.

**Note:** I'm not sure if the positive definiteness of $M$ is helpful here or not, but in the context where I encountered this problem, $M$ is posdef so I added that condition. But it could be irrelevant.

Comment: What if $M$ is diagonal? The only constraints you get are $x_i = sign (M_ii x_i )$. What possibilities for $x$ does each of these constraints eliminate?

Comment: What is sign of zero in case $\sum_j M_{ij}x_j=0$?

Comment: @AHusain $M$ diagonal is the trivial case, because $M_i>0$ and thus all $x$ of the hypercube are admissible. I am more interested in $M$ non-diagonal.

Comment: @SungjinKim You can take $\operatorname{sign}(0)=0$. I don't think that makes a big difference, though.